# Creating unique keys from list

Tags: list-manipulation, algorithm

I have the following (example) list:

```
list = {"b", "a", "b", "b", "a", "c", "c", "c", "d", "b", "aa"};
```

and want to distinguish its elements by appending a counter in the
following manner:

```
ord = Ordering @ Ordering @ list;

Part[#, ord]& @ Flatten[#, 1]& @ 
   MapIndexed[{#1, Last @ #2}&, #, {2}] & @ Gather @ Sort @ list
```

> {{"b", 1}, {"a", 1}, {"b", 2}, {"b", 3}, {"a", 2}, {"c", 1}, {"c", 2},
>   {"c", 3}, {"d", 1}, {"b", 4}, {"aa", 1}}

This solution is somehow "expensive" (three ordering / sorting) operations, so the question is:

Are there more efficient alternatives?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
list = {"b", "a", "b", "b", "a", "c", "c", "c", "d", "b", "aa"}
c = Association[# -> 0 & /@ Union@list]
{#, c[#] += 1} & /@ list
```

> {{"b", 1}, {"a", 1}, {"b", 2}, {"b", 3}, {"a", 2}, {"c", 1}, {"c", 
>     2}, {"c", 3}, {"d", 1}, {"b", 4}, {"aa", 1}}

Answer (score 11):

```
Clear[f]
f[_] = 0;
(f[#] = f[#] + 1; {f[#], #}) & /@ list
```

> `{{1, "b"}, {1, "a"}, {2, "b"}, {3, "b"}, {2, "a"}, {1, "c"}, {2,
>
>   "c"}, {3, "c"}, {1, "d"}, {4, "b"}, {1, "aa"}}`

Comment: Can be shortened to `f[_] = 0; {++f[#], #} & /@ list`

Comment: Even better is `Clear[f]; f[_] = 0; {#, ++f[#]} & /@ list`

Answer (score 5):

Functional style:

```
FoldPairList[With[{c = Lookup[#1, #2, 1]}, 
   {{#2, c}, Append[#1, #2 -> c + 1]}] &, <||>, list]
```